# Incorrect date format when writing to CSV through Java

Tags: java, csv, bufferedwriter

So, I have a method that writes some of list of objects to CSV.

```
private void writeToCSV(List<Employee> empList) {
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+"Test.csv"), "UTF-8"))) {
        empList.forEach(eachEmployee -> {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(eachEmployee.getName());
            builder.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
            builder.append(eachEmployee.getID());
            builder.append(CSV_SEPARATOR);
            builder.append(eachEmployee.getJoiningDate());
            writer.write(builder.toString());
            writer.newLine();
        });
    }
}
```

Here, the Joining date of the employee is in the format of 2019/03/20 i.e. yyyy/MM/dd format. And I am supposed to write it in the same format to CSV as well.
But when I check the CSV it is in 03/20/2019 i.e. MM/dd/yyyy format.
Any idea about where am I going wrong?

Edit : The Joining date is a type of string

Comment: what is type of joining date ? a string or date object?

Comment: updated the question. It is a type of String

Comment: You need to parse the string into a date object and then back to a string again.

Comment: How did you check your CSV? By chance, you opened it in Excel? In that case, Excel may have converted it. Try to open the file with a simple texteditor.

Comment: @RobertKock Yes, I did open it in an excel. Is there something I can do to counter this behavior of Excel?

Comment: Apparently, your CSV is correct. After having opened the file in Excel, change the format of the corresponding column by right-clicking on the column header and selecting 'Cell format'.

Answer (score 0):

## `Locale`

Your JVM’s current default `Locale` is likely being applied implicitly while generating text to represent the value of the date. I can only guess because you neglected to explain what the called method does and what is the data type of its returned value.

## *java.time*

Likely too your code is using the tragically flawed date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310.

The ultimate solution would be to adopt the *java.time* classes in your code.

## ISO 8601

And learn to use standard ISO 8601 formats when serializing date-time values as text. For dates that is YYYY-MM-DD format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when generating/parsing strings.